# Why does the following formula of multiplying and adding 1 always work?

Tags: proof-explanation, arithmetic

I was coming back from somewhere on the bus. I was playing with my calculator and managed to realized this formula:

> 9 * 9 = 81
> 10 * 10 = 100
> 100 - (9 + 9 + 1) = 81

So the formula is that you multiply `x` by `x`, then multiply `x + 1` by `x + 1`, then `(x + 1) * (x + 1) - (x + x + 1)` will always give the result of `x * x`. I wonder why.

So I use the programming language `python` to check whether this always works or not, it does always work!

```
x = 4 # assign x as 4
a = x * x # assign a as x times x
b = (x + 1) * (x + 1) # assign b as (x + 1) times (x + 1)
c = b - (x + x + 1) # assigns c as b minus (x + x + 1)
print(a == c) # checks whether a equals to c
print(c) # outputs c
print(a) # outputs a
```

And the above code outputs:

```
True
16
16
```

I wonder why it's like this, I tested with all numbers and it always works.

Could anyone explain to me the logic?

Comment: Uhm... $x^2=x^2+2x+1-2x-1=(x+1)^2-(x+x+1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the development of

$$(x+1)(x+1)= x(x+1) + (x+1)= x^2 +2x+1$$

When you sum two numbers and multiply the result by a third one, you obtain the same result when you make the sum of the first one multiplied by the third one plus the second one multiplied by the third one.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $x \times x=x^2$
and $(x+1)\times (x+1)-(x+x+1)=x^2+2x+1-(2x+1)=x^2$

These two are equivalent when you simplify them which is why they  are equal for all numbers/inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $(x+1)(x+1)=x^2+2x+1$
as $(x+1)(x+1)-2x-1= x^2$.